# double covariance

Tags: c#, covariance

I have

```
public interface IFoo
{
   IEnumerable<IThingy> Thingies{get;}
}
```

I want to then be able to do

```
class Thing1 : IThingy
{
   ...
}
class ImplementFoo : IFoo
{
   List<Thing1> m_things;
   IEnumerable<IThingy> Thingies {get {return m_things;}}
}
```

ImplementFoo.Thingies returns an IList (which is an IEnumerable) of Thing1s (which are IThings). So in theory this code should work, but it does not. VS suggests a cast in the getter; that compiles but fails at run time. Am I expecting too much of covariance in c# 4?

VS 2010 -> Silverlight 4. Here's the compile error

> Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Collections.Generic.List<MyProj.Column>`' to '`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyProj.IColumn>`'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

EDIT: People tell me this should work, but it doesnt work in SL4

Comment: Are you targeting .NET 4 in your project?

Comment: .net 4 for sure. LEt me try again. Actually Silverlight 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THis is a difference between SL4 and CLR4. THe IEnumerable interface is not marked 'out'. Apparently fixed in SL5

Answer (score 2):

This works fine in C#/.NET 4.  Here is a full, compiling and working sample:

```
namespace Test
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    public interface IThingy { }

    public interface IFoo
    {
        IEnumerable<IThingy> Thingies { get; }
    }

    internal class Thing1 : IThingy { }

    internal class ImplementFoo : IFoo
    {
        private List<Thing1> m_things = new List<Thing1>() { new Thing1() };

        public IEnumerable<IThingy> Thingies
        {
            get { return m_things; }
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var impl = new ImplementFoo();

            Console.WriteLine(impl.Thingies.Count());


            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect the problem is you're targeting .NET 3.5sp1 or earlier, not .NET 4.0.  Covariance will only work properly when targeting .NET 4, as it requires the new framework changes.  In this case, `IEnumerable<T>`, in .NET 4, is actually [`IEnumerable<out T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx), which is required for this to work.

Comment: That explains why it wasn't working for me, I was testing with `ICollection<>` and `Collection<>`.  Seems ICollection is not `out T`.

Comment: @Anthony: `ICollection<T>` has methods which take a T as input. If you have a collection of Bananas, and you can treat it as a collection of Fruit, then you can put an Orange into a collection of Bananas. That shouldn't be legal, so the collection interface is not allowed to be covariant in T.

Comment: @Anthony Sottile Yes, that's correct. ICollection isn't one of the interfaces that was made co/contra-variant in 4.0.

Comment: @Eric makes sense now.  Guess I should have thought about the implications of being an editable collection, now my comment just sounds stupid :P

Comment: @Anthony: No worries; this stuff is tricky to get your brain around!

Comment: @Reed Copsey - its silverlight 4 - does that count as .Net4. I edited my question to show the compile error

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Cast extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx):

```
class ImplementFoo : IFoo
{
    List<Thing1> m_things;

    IEnumerable<IThingy> Thingies 
    {
        get
        {
            return m_things.Cast<IThingy>();
        }
    }
}
```

This is because `IEnumerable<Thing1>` does not implicitly implement `IEnumerable<IThingy>`.

Comment: Hmmm, looking at Reed's answer, then perhaps I'm giving a pre-.NET 4 answer here...

Comment: This actually does work in .NET 4.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx

Comment: Nice! I hadn't noticed this new feature, I've become accustomed to just tacking on the cast call... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465120.aspx